# Is it possible to authenticate users through different subdomains?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, multi-tenant

I would like to create a multi-tentant [laravel](https://laravel.com/) 8.0 application (with [laravel multi-tenancy package](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/introduction) and [laravel sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum)) with Vue Frontend for the customers and a Vue Frontend for Admins.

**([Vue](https://vuejs.org/)2) Frontend for customers** like: *example.com* and *store1.example.com* and *store2.example.com*

**([Vue](https://vuejs.org/)2) Frontend for admins** like: *store1.admin.example.com* and *store2.example.com*

**([Laravel](https://laravel.com/)) Backend** for the rest api like: *store1.api.example.com* and *store2.api.example.com*

**I would like to make it possible for customers to log in on any of the subdomains** forexample on *example.com* or on *store1.example.com* **and also be logged in on all the other subdomains.**

**Is it possible?**
**Do you have any suggestions?**

*+1 question: Is there any way to generate a subdomain with laravel?*

*This would be my first multi-tenant sandbox application, thanks for your help!*

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar set-up with this although I haven't gotten to a deeper sub-domain.

The first thing you need to do is configure the tld and wildcard sub-domain to your application, so whatever subdomain you hit, you should always see the index content.

The first setup for this is to set `SESSION_DOMAIN` in laravel `.env` to  something like `.whatever.com`
e.g.

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.whatever.com
```

Then the next thing you have to do is to make sure your application uses JWT Authentication https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

and when you save the token on your user browser, you need to set the domain same as your `SESSION_DOMAIN`.

I grab the tld no matter what subdomain they try to log-in

```
const tld = (() => {
  const host = window.location.host, subs = host.split('.')
  if ( subs.length > 2 ) 
    return host.replace(/^[^.]+\./g, "")
  return host
})()
```

then I added `.` in-front of the tld on domain cookies that holds the token

```
Cookies.set('token', token, { expires: remember ? 365 : null,  domain: `.${tld}` })
```

so if you go to Application tab from dev toolbar, then under cookies on your app, the domain should be `.whatever.com` and if you jump from one sub-domain to another you should still be authenticated
[image]

Also, regarding with your setup, I think you are just over-using a subdomain in your initial plan.

You can just simply create a table for **STORE** which holds all different store then add a column for `slug`. then just create one-to-many or many-to-many relationship for other stuff like store owner from users table, store products from products table etc, so you store table should just look like

```
id |    name  | slug
 1 | My Store | store1
```

Then on the front-end, you would grab the slug of the sub-domain and request a query with matching store `slug` to your API end-point, you only need one structure for your end-point, you don't need to have each store have their own api end-point, you just need to include the store slug every time you hit your end-point which are store specific request, so if you hit store1.whatever.com, all your query should pull everything related to a store with slug `store1`

Additionally, you don't need to use a sub-domain for admin and api end-point, try looking for a Vue+Laravel template, like this one below which has a lot of features like vue routing, vuex and templating which I think is very suitable for your set-up https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa

Then the way you should handle it is much better to be something like this

**Front-end** -> `store1.whatever.com`

**Admin** -> `store1.whatever.com/admin/`

**API end-point** -> `whatever.com/api/`

Comment: Thank you for your help! The project is just in planning status, but your idea is the closest one to the final plan, you helped a lot. 
The important thing is to make all stores accessable from their subfomain, like store1.example.com while the customer dont have to log in again and again after navigating between stores. To not have subdomains for the api and the admin frontend is a very cool idea. Sometimes i a littlebit over engeenering things when its new or complex for me. :)  Is it a must to use JWT or is it possible to make it with Latavel Sanctum (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum)

Comment: And one more important question. 

Stores should be stored in database like name domain etc.. when i create a new store the only thing i must create is a new subdomain for it right? Not deploying a new frontend application for each stores right?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with sanctum as I've only been using just JWT for almost a decade. but no matter what authentication method you use, the idea should still be the same as I mentioned above. as for your store set-up, I mention to use vue TEMPLATING structure to handle different store, checkout and play around that laravel-vue-spa I reference, that should get you started, it uses JWT by default, but you can replace is with sanctum if you want

Comment: and by the way, as I mentioned, you don't need to create a subdomain for each store, just configure the wildcard sub and point it on your app, so if you hit ```store1.whatever.com``` the first query you should do is to check if that ```sub``` exist on your store table, otherwise just handle redirect or something inside your vue to handle request from non-existent store ```sub```